# Make Tkinter Label and Frame Transparent Linux

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, transparent

I'm creating a custom Virtual Cockpit for my car, and I would like the Tkinter background to be transparent so that I can run another program behind it.

I've tried

```
master.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
```

But this seems to only work with Windows and will return a `bad attribute` with Linux.

My Test Code (Works in Windows):

```
try:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('430x480+50+50')
root.title("Transparency Test")
root["bg"] = "black"

layer = PhotoImage(file ="rpm-overlay-overlay.png")
topFrame = Label(text="Ping Checker", bg="black", image=layer, fg="#fff", font="Bahnschrift 14")
topFrame.place(x=11,y=10)

topFrame.pack_forget()
topFrame.pack()

root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: you can't make it transparent on Linux. Use PyQt/PySide, PyGtk, wxPython instead of tkinter.

Comment: I can't get any of them to give me a transparent window using a Rapsberry Pi on Python 2.7.16

Comment: it shouldn't be problem to install it on Raspberry. If you use [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) (Debian on Raspberry) then you use windows manager [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) which uses Gtk. And maybe it already has installed PyGtk. Some other programs may use Qt so it may need only PyQt or PySide. More problems can be with wxPython which install wxWindows and it has to compile it from C/C++ and it may takes hours.

Comment: there is tutorial for [transparent window with PyGtk](http://zetcode.com/gfx/pycairo/root/). There are more tutorials for PyGtk, PyQt, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

```
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
```

0.5 can be anything between 0 (being fully visible) and 1 (being fully *in*visible)